# Cocoapods: How to get the git repo address for the pod you've installed?

Tags: cocoapods

I'm working an old project with many pods depended on. Some of them are public pods on Github and some of them are private pods distributed on the server inside my company.

My problem is how do I get to know from where I downloaded these pods?

By local pods I didn't mean the pod developed inside my project, but pods developed inside my company and distributed only on repos inside company, all I have to do is to write the pod name, and Cocoapods will search all repos, inside or outside, and download them. There is no difference between them in Podfile.

Comment: Do you have the `Podfile` ?

Comment: Yes I do, and there are some inside-company repos set for cocoa pods

Comment: So you have the answer: local pods are in the form `:path => '~/Documents/AFNetworking'` and all others are dictated by either the assumption or the explicit declaration `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`.

Comment: By local pods I didn't mean the pod developed inside my project, but pods developed inside my company and distributed only on repos inside company, all I have to do is to write the pod name, and Cocoapods will search all repos, inside or outside, and download them. They is no difference between them in Podfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, I used the dumb but effective idea.

I clean my Pods folder and run `pod update --verbose > ~/Desktop/log.txt`, and by reading the log, I can see where I got every pod.

Any better idea will be accepted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Local pods are present at ~/.cocoapods/repos. You can simply use `find` command to look for the intended pod path.

To find a pod named 'XYZ' use -

```
find ~/.cocoapods/repos -type d -name "XYZ" -print
```

This will print the pod path to the console.

Now, you can `cd` into the pod directory & check the latest version's `podspec.json` file for that pod to find the source & other details.